# О человеке неизвестного пола

Tags: согласование, грамотная-речь, оформление-текста

Я пытаюсь сформулировать сообщения о человеке неизвестного пола, вроде таких:

> Этот/та/а пользователь(ница) прислал(-а) вам сообщение.
>   Опытный(ая) спортсмен(-ка) тренировался/лась/ась весь год.

Есть ли правила, как такое писать?
Я только знаю, что пишут мужской род и добавляют окончания женского.
Но как именно добавлять: (ая), (-ая), ый/ая?
И сколько букв?

И как такое вообще называется? Наращения -- это ведь у числительных, а здесь что-то другое.

Пояснение: Мне нужно составить шаблоны для генерации сообщений программой. Тот, кто читает сообщения, скорее всего знает пол того, о ком они, а программа -- не всегда.
Сообщения, которые меня интересуют, начинаются обычно со слов "Этот пользователь"  или "Пользователь <имя_пользователя>. Например, "Пользователь *Юля* с вами еще не переписывался"

Answer (score 3):

Углубленное гугление показало, что на сайтах, форумах и в блогах люди пишут, как попало. В словарях тоже отдельные нормы.
Но в книгах, прошедших редакторскую правку, можно заметить некоторые закономерности:

- Если слово женского рода это слово мужского рода + суффикс с окончанием, то добавочные буквы пишутся просто в скобках. Например, пользователь(ница)".
- Если другой вариант составляет целое слово, его тоже пишут в скобках. Например, "супруг(а), (друг, подруга)"
- Если в женском роде окончание слова меняется, то женский вариант окончания пишут в скобках и с дефисом, или без дефиса. Например, "зарегистрировался(-лась), зарегистрировался(лась), зарегистрировался(ась)".
  То есть даже количество букв в скобках бывает разным!

Надеюсь, кто-то все же добавит сюда ответ с настоящим правилом.
Остается также открытым вопрос, как же называется это правило.

Answer (score 2):

Такие попытки только усложнят форму. Первая фраза должна быть универсальна: **Этот пользователь прислал Вам сообщение**. Вторая также должна позволить всякому без "подчёркивания нужного" сразу перейти к сути, и её можно обозначить так, например: **Квалификация и спортивная форма спортсмена**.

Comment: А если это "Пользователь Таня прислал вам сообщение"? Или имя непонятное, но на аватаре видно, что "этот пользователь" женского пола?

Comment: Если Татьяна по занятости директор школы, завуч или врач, то на досуге почему бы ей не быть пользователем?

Comment: "Директор школы Татьяна **прислал** вам сообщение".

Comment: Пользователь прислал и никак иначе. Сетевой стандарт. Директор в данном случае – из другой реальности. Взбалтывать можно, но не надо смешивать.

Comment: Решить задачу можно также, объединив сообщения пользователей в группы . Множественное число не имеет рода: Эти пользователи прислали Вам сообщение.